# extract value from JSON with jq

Tags: jq

I make a call to an HPE iLO to pull back SNMP v3 user information.  I get:

```
curl --silent --insecure --header "X-API-Token: ${iLOAuth}" --request GET ${iLOSSO}/redfish/v1/Managers/v1/snmpservice/snmpusers | jq -r '.Members[]'
```

and get back:

```
{
   "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/SNMPUsers/1"
}
{
   "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SnmpService/SNMPUsers/3"
}
```

I just want to get back the values, but if I try:

```
jq -r '.Members[] | .@odata.id'
```

I get back an error.  Does anyone know the proper syntax to use?

Comment: `.Members[] | ."@odata.id"`  or `.Members[] | .["@odata.id"]`

Comment: Found the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809577/json-object-contains-odata-id-how-to-get-it-out).  If I use `jq -r '.Members[] | .["@data.id"]'` I get the correct values.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: I think part of my confusion was I saw the output as above.  It was really: `[ "@odata.id":...` an array.